# Rendering SwiftUI View to UIImage at a deeper navigation level

Tags: image, swiftui, navigation, render

I need to render a SwiftUI View to an UIImage without displaying it for sharing purposes, but the solutions I found here are not working if I do the rendering in a View referred by a NavigationLink.

Here is a minimal example for reproducing my problem:

SampleView.swift (the one I need rendered as UIImage)

```
struct SampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "globe").ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    
    func getImage() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        controller.view.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = 1
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: controller.view.layer.frame.size, format: format).image { context in
            controller.view.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.layer.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var image: UIImage
    
    init() {
        self.image = SampleView().getImage()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("MainContentView")
                Image(uiImage: self.image) //working
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SubContentView()
                ) {
                    Text("NavigationLink")
                } // end of navigationLink
            } // end of vstack
        } // end of navigationview
    }
}
```

SubContentView.swift

```
struct SubContentView: View {
    
    var image: UIImage
    
    init() {
        self.image = SampleView().getImage()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("SubContentView")
            Image(uiImage: self.image)
        }
    }
}
```

The SampleView will be rendered correctly at my ContentView, but is rendered to a blank image at my SubContentView.

Xcode is showing following error message on output

```
2023-08-04 23:46:48.901870+0200 ViewRenderToImageTest[9929:192715] [Snapshotting] View (0x156f0e140, _TtGC7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewV21ViewRenderToImageTest10SampleView_) drawing with afterScreenUpdates:YES inside CoreAnimation commit is not supported.
```

How to render my SampleView correctly to an image from the SubContentView?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine i moved the getImage function to a helper class with static function `class ViewHelper {public static func getImage(v: some View) -> UIImage {...}`but still getting the same result (blank image at SubContentView).
Also tried to move the getImage function to an extension of View (`extension View { public func getImage() -> UIImage {...`) as suggested in most other questions, but also just get a blank image at the SubContentView.

Comment: yes, I tried all these options as well without success yet, that is why I deleted my comment. Note, I don't get any errors, just no image in the `SubContentView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the log message, it seems like at the time that you call `getImage`, it is in the middle of a Core Animation transaction (in order to show the `SubContentView`), and that makes it unable to draw the view. There was no transaction when showing the `ContentView`, probably because it is the root.

Therefore, I tried putting the `getImage` call inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`. The idea is to allow the main queue to finish the transaction, and only *then* draw the view. This worked.

```
struct SubContentView: View {
    
    @State var image: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("SubContentView")
            if let image {
                Image(uiImage: image)
            }
        }.onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                image = SampleView().getImage()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that image creation needs to be asynchronous. This works for me in the demo project.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it fully solves the issue in my demo project. When i adapt my main project to use this solution the image creation works perfectly, but still getting the error message.